# android implement listener in fragment

Tags: android

I am new in Android development. I want to add a listener in my fragment which upon button click will send a message. I need to listen to this in my main fragment class so that my activity can access this main fragment and process the message. I also need to remove the listener in my main fragment. So how do I implement this?

**EDIT**

I have `MyFragment`

`sendMessage(message)` is a method in `MyFragment` which has a button click. Need to implement listener here?

In `MainFragment`
How to handle this `sendMessage` event here and send to `MAinActivity`

The flow is like `MyFragment(childfragment) -> MAinFragment -> MainActivity`

Comment: Welcome on stackoverflow. What you are trying yet?

Answer (score 3):

In your fragment class, say MyFragment.java create an interface

```
public interface MyFragmentInterfacer{
    void onButtonClick(String msg);
}
MyFragmentInterfacer fragmentInterfacer;

//Override this function as below to set fragmentInterfacer
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context){
    fragmentInterfacer = (MyFragmentInterfacer)context;
}
```

and where you want to invoke this function

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        if(fragmentInterfacer != null){
             fragmentInterfacer.onButtonClick("This is my Message");
        }
    }
});
```

Then in your main activity where you want to get this message, implement this interface

```
public class MainActivity implements MyFragment.MyFragmentInterfacer{
.
.
}
```

and then implement the interface function in MainActivity

```
@Override
public void onButtonClick(String msg){
    //Do something with this message
}
```

To remove this listener, use

```
fragmentInterfacer = null;
```

in your fragment class when you want to disable this listener.

Or you can remove the onClickListener from button

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(null);
```

or disable clicking on button

```
myButton.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: Is this really the best way?!?! There must be better ways of setting a listener on a fragment.